# Why am I getting "value for the column is too long" for docx file in prisma and sql-server?

Tags: sql-server, typescript, express, prisma

I'm getting the error "**The provided value for the column is too long for the column's type. Column: (not available)**" from prisma (4.2.1) when I'm trying to insert a file as a buffer to a varbinary(max) column.

**Stack trace:**

> Invalid `prisma.ticket.create()` invocation in
> D:\Repositories\GitHub\React\ticketify\Backend\src\routes\Ticket.ts:83:47
>
> 80 ticket = validation.value;
> 81
> 82 const filesToCreate =
> files.map(file => fileParams(file));
> →  83 const newTicket = await
> prisma.ticket.create(   The provided value for the column is too long
> for the column's type. Column: (not available)
> at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (D:\Repositories\GitHub\React\ticketify\Backend\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:28838:13)
> at RequestHandler.request (D:\Repositories\GitHub\React\ticketify\Backend\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:28820:12)
> at async userSignature (D:\Repositories\GitHub\React\ticketify\Backend\src\middlewares\prisma\userSignature.ts:12:13)
> at async D:\Repositories\GitHub\React\ticketify\Backend\src\middlewares\prisma\ticketActivity.ts:44:17
> at async PrismaClient._request (D:\Repositories\GitHub\React\ticketify\Backend\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:29753:16)
> at async D:\Repositories\GitHub\React\ticketify\Backend\src\routes\Ticket.ts:83:27

I have the following schemas.
**Ticket**:

```
model Ticket {
  id                Int              @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.Int
  attachments       FileOnTicket[]
  ...
}
```

The **FileOnTicket** model is just a mapping table for file and ticket:

```
model FileOnTicket {
  fileId   String @db.NVarChar(100)
  file     File   @relation(fields: [fileId], references: [id])
  ticketId Int    @db.Int
  ticket   Ticket @relation(fields: [ticketId], references: [id])

  @@id([fileId, ticketId])
}
```

And finally, here's the **file** table:

```
model File {
  id               String         @id @default(uuid()) @db.NVarChar(100)
  fileName         String?        @db.NVarChar(100)
  content          Bytes
  ...
}
```

I create an attachment like so:

```
const newTicket = await prisma.ticket.create({
        data: {
            ...ticket,
            attachments: {
                create: filesToCreate.map(file => {
                    return {
                        file: {
                            create: file
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
});
```

Prisma maps the **Bytes** type to **varbinary(max)** column type so the size shouldn't be a problem. I get the error with an docx file that is 11.5 KB long.

I tested it with **text** and **image** files so far. They were all larger, like a few MB or so.
I wonder why I am getting the "**column is too large error**". Maybe there is an other error hiding behind it?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you please post the full error message here? Also, maybe enable debug output with `DEBUG=*` environment variable set.

Comment: @HarshitPant added full stack trace. Also enabled debug output but I don't get helpful output for it. You can also see the content of the file as string (I think it is base64) which is definetely not too long and the same stack trace.